# Login with JS and then using PHP SDK (Facebook)

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using this code to login my website via facebook:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
     FB.init({ 
            appId:'MYAPPID', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
     });
</script>
<fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Its working well and I see my application on `facebook.com/editapps.php`, but then when I want to start using PHP SDK I see that I didn't login. If I login via PHP SDK then I see that I logged in.. What is the problem here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of PHP SDK are you using? Because the latest 3.0.1 isn't compatible yet with javascript SDK. So you would need to downgrade to version 2 of the SDK until they will update the Javascript SDK too.

More info about this here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/

Comment: Oh, now I see.. what about 3.0? or I should be with the last 2.x? thank you.

Comment: You have two options here. If you want to use the current Javascript SDK, then you have to use the PHP SKD 2.x. Or you can wait for the new release of the Javascript SDK to use the PHP SDK 3.x (I would recommend that, only one or two weeks to wait...)